# Multi-Layer Perceptron first layer weights

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network

In a Multi-Layer Perceptron network, Do the input layer's weights (like W00 and W01) change in learning process (when backpropagation algorithm is running) or they are always fixed to 1?
[image]

Comment: i think there might be a more specific SE site for this question ...

Comment: Why would they be fixed to 1?

Comment: @BenedictWilkinsAI Because it's the input of the network and input must remain intact?

Comment: @Fattie What do you mean SE site?

Comment: @ARK1375  You are using SE. Stack Exchange.  try this site:  https://ai.stackexchange.com

Comment: or possibly https://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: (I'm not certain - it's often hard to know where a question should be..)

Comment: @ARK1375 I suggest you read a book on the basics of deep learning to get a better understanding, for example: https://www.deeplearningbook.org/

Comment: sound advice, @BenedictWilkinsAI  :)